# Bar plot with negative and positive values centered on a non-zero value

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar graph of odds ratios. Interpretationally, they are centered around 1, not 0. Therefore, I would like to have a bar graph where values below 1 are "negative" and values above 1 are "positive" (i.e., a graph of distance from 1).

Effectively, the graph should look like the following plot except that the labels on the y axis should be centered around 1, not 0.

[image: the plot]

I would like to create this graph not be relabeling of the y axis, but by actually centering it around 1. Is this possible; and if so, how?

Code to create the example graph:

```
data <- matrix(c(rnorm(5, 1, .5)), 5, 1)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data[,2] <- data[,1] - .1
data[,3] <- data[,1] + .1
data <- cbind(c(letters[1:5]), data)
names(data) <- c("Category", "OR", "Lower", "Upper")

data.zero <- cbind("Category"=data[,1], data[,2:4] - 1)

require(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = data.zero, aes(x=Category, y=OR, fill=Category), stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = 1) +  
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Category, y=OR, ymin=Lower, ymax=Upper), 
            width=.1, position=position_dodge(), data=data.zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a simple function to add 1, like so:

```
plus1_formatter <- function(x) {x +1}
```

and than add the string

```
+ scale_y_continuous(labels=plus1_formatter)
```

to your ggplot command above.

to make it reproducible set `seed(123)`

before:
[image: before changing the labels]

after:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you don't want to relabel the y-axis, you want it centered to 1.

```
## Find the minimum and maximum y
mi <- min(data.zero$Lower)
ma <- max(data.zero$Upper)
```

Now I check which distance is greater, from 1 to mi or from 1 to ma. I set the ylim by increasing the smaller distance from 1.

```
if(1 - mi > ma - 1) { 
    newylim <- c(mi  , 2 - mi)  ## Lower limit remains same, Upper limit is increased
} else { 
    newylim <- c(2 - ma, ma)    ## Upper limit remains same, Lower limit is decreased
}
```

then you can plot adding:

```
+ ylim(newylim)
```

The plot with your code is in the left and adding the `ylim` in the right.

[image]

Hope it helps,

alex