# Make a tornado plot using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have table of 3 variables (H, M, S) with max and min values.

```
structure(c(29.2933333333333, 9.29333333333333, 17.7688888888889, 
20.8177777777778, 26.97, 3.93999999999999), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
c("high", "low"), c("height", "mass", "strands")))
```

I want to plot these values on a tornado plot, and separate the values if they are higher/lower than a baseline of 19.
The end product should be something like this:

[image]

Thanks so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24932695/786542

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the aim well, we can use:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Level=as.factor(row.names(.))) %>% 
  gather(key,value,-Level) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(key,value,fill=Level))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity")+
  coord_flip()
```

Option 2:

```
df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Level=as.factor(row.names(.))) %>% 
  gather(key,value,-Level) %>% 
  mutate(Level=ifelse(value>19,"high","low")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(key,value,fill=Level))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity")+
  coord_flip()
```

Result for option 1:
[image]